# Parse InputStream "on the fly" / re-use an InputStream

Tags: java, xml-parsing, inputstream

I have an InputStream which contains XML data which I would like to parse before returning the InputStream.

```
InputStream is = myObj.getInputStream();

// parse Inputstream here

return is;
```

Of course I could save the stream as a byte array and return a new InputStream from that or

create a second InputStream on 'myObj'.

But is there any way to parse the stream 'on the fly'?

**Edit:**

Basically I am searching for a way to re-use the stream after parsing. Sort of parsing the stream without consuming it, respectively to reset it after the parsing.

**Solution:**

The solution I've found is to use a BufferedInputStream (Note from the comments: That will only work up to 8k bytes)

```
BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream ( myObj.getInputStream() );

is.mark( Integer.MIN_VALUE );

// parse Inputstream here

is.reset();

return is;
```

Answer (score 2):

To parse *on the fly*, without waiting the end of stream you can use a [Sax Parser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html).

A sax parser is event based so it is not necessary to read the whole document before processing it. With that the process is something like:

- THe tag person is open
- The tag name is open
- The tag name is closed
- the tag surname is opened
- the tag surname is closed
- the tag person is closed

For each event you need to execute some custom code.

Working with a sax parser is a little more difficult than a dom parser but has some advantages. Over all it needs less resources and you don't need to wait to have the whole document.

Comment: The main problem is, that I can consume the InputStream only once. Will the Sax Parser consume the InputStream or will the stream be returned like it wasn't touched?

Answer (score 0):

This can be quite complicated because the best candidate for on-the-fly xml parsing the [SAX Parser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html). By necessity it is event driven and relies on callback methods to indicate events in the incoming stream.

I have implemented something like this by doing the following:

1. Create a Queue.
2. Fire off a thread that parses the XML using the SAXParser pushing the results into the Queue.
3. Iterate over the queue.

This is not simple but it is stable and reliable. I will try to post some demo code.

Answer (score -1):

The solution I've found (at least the one that works for me) is to use a BufferedInputStream:

```
BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream ( myObj.getInputStream() );

is.mark( Integer.MIN_VALUE );

// parse Inputstream here

is.reset();

return is;
```

Comment: That will only work up to 8k bytes, or whatever buffer size you specify when constructing the buffered input stream.